# What is the difference between a return and a break in an infinite loop?

Tags: return, rust, infinite-loop, break

In doing the Guessing Game from the Rust Book (I won't put the link because it will probably not exist in a few weeks), there is a point where you use `return` to break out of the `loop`. I used `break` instead:

```rust
loop {
    guess = guesser();
    guess_cast = guess.trim().parse();

    let guess_num = match guess_cast {
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Guess was not a number, try again");
            continue;
        },
    };

    if guess_num < answer {
        println!("Too low");
    } else if guess_num > answer {
        println!("Too high");
    } else {
        println!("You guessed it!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there a real difference in using `return` over `break` in this case? What about other cases when you want to break out of an infinite loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the loop is the final statement in the function, then there is patently no functional distinction between `break;` and `return;`. If this condition does not hold, there is evidently a difference, for `return` terminates execution of the *function*, while `break` only terminates execution of the *loop*.

In the case where they are functionally the same, which you use may vary based on context (which one feels better in this particular location), personal preference and what, if anything, you ate for breakfast.

Comment: I expect a thorough blog post correlating breakfast choices and how they map to `return` / `break`.

Comment: @Chris Morgan, concise and clear. It was late night, so no breakfast was taken until today, after that I decided to use `return` since this is the last loop in the program and should end execution after.